# Canvas(View) Rotation animation stops before given duration

Tags: android, performance, animation, android-animation

I am trying to rotate a view for specific duration (9 seconds) in some devices it is perfectly running for 9 sec but in few devices animation is getting stopped before the given duration.

it is working perfectly in Samsung s6, OPPO A37fw, VIVO Y21L, MI All devices, and NOT WORKING in LYF Wind 5,SAMSUNG DUOS, Xolo Tab of 2GB RAM, Android TV and some other devices

```
public void rotateWheelToTarget(int target) {
    float wheelItemCenter = 270 - getAngleOfIndexTarget(target) + (360 / mWheelItems.size()) / 2;

    animate().setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator())
            .setDuration(DEFAULT_ROTATION_TIME)
            .rotation((360 * 10) + wheelItemCenter)
            .setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    if (mOnLuckyWheelReachTheTarget != null) {
                        mOnLuckyWheelReachTheTarget.onReachTarget();
                    }

                    clearAnimation();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                }
            })
            .start();
}
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: in which devices it stopped before the time specified ?

Comment: it is working perfectly in Samsung s6, OPPO A37fw, VIVO Y21L, MI All devices, and NOT WORKIN in LYF Wind 5,SAMSUNG DUOS, Xolo Tab of 2GB RAM, Android TV and some other devies

Comment: so not working in lollipop right ?

Comment: OS is not specific, it is not working on which I tried are ,Jelly Bean, Lolipop, Marshmellow

Comment: ok, did you used xml for animation ? show it..

Comment: I tried it through xml before but getting same problem so I switched to this code